# How to link GND vias to the GND plane

Tags: pcb-design, altium, ground, pcb-layers

[image: PCB vias and components]

I know that it's possible for the GND vias to connect to the GND signal layer in a 4 layer stack. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Polygon properties, pour over all same net objects.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @9_daytona's answer, you can view a more comprehensive list of polygons in:

Tools -> Polygon Pours -> Polygon Manager.

[image]

You can update the net name in this window, as well as creating a New Polygon Pour -> From Board Outline to take the exact shape of your board.

Answer (score 1):

[image: PCB layer in altium designer]

1. Select the  layer from the bottom
2. Properties > Net